# Cannot use object of type book as array

Tags: php, arrays, oop

I have a PHP class called "book": I've made various instances of it and placed them in an array called `$books`. I know this is not the best approach in PHP but I've learned OOP in JavaScript and that's how I usually do this.

var_dump of `$books` will produce

```
array(2) { [0]=> object(book)#3 (6) { // some properties }
[1]=> object(book)#4 (6) { // some properties } }
```

I've always been able to iterate in array of objects with `foreach($books as $book)` but this time I get the error:

> Cannot use object of type book as array

Var dump says it is an array: error reporting says is an object. Why is this?

`$books` is created with `$books = array();` and objects inside of it are added with `array_push()`. `$books` IS an array and not an object: is PHP crazy?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your issue looks as you are trying to iterate a Book object instead of an array of Book objects, check well your array and vars; probably your are assigning an object to your array var instead append it to your array

Comment: Great, then check my post as answer :D  best regards and good luck

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure `$books` is an array? It looks like you're trying to iterate over a *book* object.

There is no `$books.length` notation in PHP. If anything it should be `$books->length` but since `$books` is an array it's  `count($books)`. Arrays are not Objects in PHP, unlike JavaScript.

Comment: you're right - I've edited the question when you were posting. count($books) works fine and I'm sure it is an array as you can see from the var_dump.